# Как узнать весь путь до rest метода в spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, get

Я тестирую чужой проект.
В нем есть контроллер api которого я хочу проверить.

как узнать путь до этого контроллера?
http://localhost:8080// + путь + /controller/metodGet

Comment: а что именно мы ищем?

Comment: а да ок сработало.